# .pth file not migrated after Python version upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use a Python .pth file to add some local modules into my Python environment.  The .pth file is in my version-specific site-packages directory.  Every time I upgrade to a newer Python version, my implementation breaks until I manually copy the .pth file to the new site-packages directory.

Is there a way to automatically include .pth files when a new site-packages directory is created, or is there a better way to use .pth files so that they will automatically get applied when Python is upgraded?

I'm using an Arch Linux distribution, BTW.